# XSLT Validation: for-each giving error "empty sequence is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:analyze-string"

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to validate the format of a date that repeats within an XML message.  I got this same "empty string" error when I only had one date in a template.  I was able to get that template to work.  But when I add a "for-each" construct to account for a date that may repeat in the XML message, I get the error "empty sequence is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:analyze-string".  Besides the fact that I don't understand why I'm getting this error just by adding the "for-each", I'm not sure why the validation code thinks there is an empty sequence.  Although it's possible for the date to be missing (which I thought I fixed the first time around, when not using the for-each construct), my test message does have the date I am trying to test.  I read through a few other answers on the site, but either I don't understand how to apply the fix or I don't know if the suggested fixes will address my problem (I'm not a programmer).

Could someone please help me fix this code so that I can test for this date that will repeat?

The structure of the message is

```
<VXU_V04.ORDER> One or more may be present, not a required group; I’m calling this “OrderGroup”
<RXA> Required; only one RXA Segment per OrderGroup allowed
<RXA.3> Required; only one RXA.3 field per RXA Segment allowed
<TS.1> is a sub-components of RXA.3
```

Here is the relevant part of the sample message

```
 <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197023</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.17>
        <CE.1>DCS</CE.1>
        <CE.2>Dabig Clinical System</CE.2>
        <CE.3>StateIIS</CE.3>
      </ORC.17>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090415132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090415132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>31</CE.1>
        <CE.2>Hep B Peds NOS</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>01</CE.1>
        <CE.2>historical record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
    </RXA>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
  <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197027</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.12>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Pediatric</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>MARY</XCN.3>
        <XCN.10>L</XCN.10>
        <XCN.21>MD</XCN.21>
      </ORC.12>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>48</CE.1>
        <CE.2>HIB PRP-T</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>00</CE.1>
        <CE.2>new Immunization record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
      <RXA.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Sticker</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Nurse</XCN.3>
      </RXA.10>
      <RXA.11>
        <LA2.4>
          <HD.1>DCS_DC</HD.1>
        </LA2.4>
      </RXA.11>
      <RXA.15>33k2a</RXA.15>
      <RXA.17>
        <CE.1>PMC</CE.1>
        <CE.2>sanofi</CE.2>
        <CE.3>MVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.17>
    </RXA>
    <RXR>
      <RXR.1>
        <CE.1>C28161</CE.1>
        <CE.2>IM</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NCIT</CE.3>
        <CE.4>IM</CE.4>
        <CE.5>IM</CE.5>
        <CE.6>HL70162</CE.6>
      </RXR.1>
    </RXR>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
  <VXU_V04.ORDER>
    <ORC>
      <ORC.1>RE</ORC.1>
      <ORC.3>
        <EI.1>197028</EI.1>
        <EI.2>DCS</EI.2>
      </ORC.3>
      <ORC.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Clerk</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Myron</XCN.3>
      </ORC.10>
      <ORC.12>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Pediatric</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>MARY</XCN.3>
        <XCN.10>L</XCN.10>
        <XCN.21>MD</XCN.21>
      </ORC.12>
    </ORC>
    <RXA>
      <RXA.1>0</RXA.1>
      <RXA.2>1</RXA.2>
      <RXA.3>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.3>
      <RXA.4>
        <TS.1>20090531132511</TS.1>
      </RXA.4>
      <RXA.5>
        <CE.1>110</CE.1>
        <CE.2>DTAP-Hep B-IPV</CE.2>
        <CE.3>CVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.5>
      <RXA.6>999</RXA.6>
      <RXA.9>
        <CE.1>00</CE.1>
        <CE.2>new immunization record</CE.2>
        <CE.3>NIP0001</CE.3>
      </RXA.9>
      <RXA.10>
        <XCN.2>
          <FN.1>Sticker</FN.1>
        </XCN.2>
        <XCN.3>Nurse</XCN.3>
      </RXA.10>
      <RXA.11>
        <LA2.4>
          <HD.1>DCS_DC</HD.1>
        </LA2.4>
      </RXA.11>
      <RXA.15>xy3939</RXA.15>
      <RXA.17>
        <CE.1>SKB</CE.1>
        <CE.2>GSK</CE.2>
        <CE.3>MVX</CE.3>
      </RXA.17>
    </RXA>
    <RXR>
      <RXR.1>
        <CE.1>IM</CE.1>
        <CE.2>IM</CE.2>
        <CE.3>HL70162</CE.3>
        <CE.4>C28161</CE.4>
        <CE.5>IM</CE.5>
        <CE.6>NCIT</CE.6>
      </RXR.1>
    </RXR>
  </VXU_V04.ORDER>
```

Here is my validation template. I've tried a few different things like having the "for-each" statement before each "analyze-string" function.  I've tried adding a count on TS1Field but I keep getting syntax errors when I try to incorporate the count check into this:  .

I think this may be a similar issue I had where the template was not recognizing my sub-component (TS1Field).  I posted a question about that on this site and got a good answer which fixed another problem in another validation template.  However, when I try the same thing here, it's not working.

(By the way, I know I have descriptions for a different field in here - Patient Death Date - but that is from the template I used as a basis for this one.  I haven't gotten around to updating those messages yet.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:a="urn:hl7-org:v2xml" xmlns:dil="http://www.aegis.net/msg/filter/jaxb/rule" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--      
             Must be VALUED AND 
             Must not repeat
         -->
    <xsl:variable name="OrderGroup" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RXASegment" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:RXA"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RXA3Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:RXA/a:RXA.3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="TS1Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:RXA/a:TS.1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dil:filterruleresult>
             <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test= "count($OrderGroup)= 0">
                    <dil:message type="info">VXU Order Group not found.</dil:message>
                 </xsl:when>
             </xsl:choose>
             <xsl:for-each select="$OrderGroup">
                     <xsl:choose>
                       <xsl:when test="count(a:RXA)= 0">  
                          <dil:message type="error">When Order Group present, RXA Segment is required.</dil:message>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:when test="count(a:RXA)> 1">  
                        <dil:message type="error">Only one Pharmacy/Treatment Administration Segment (RXA) allowed per Order Group.</dil:message>
                       </xsl:when>
                       <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA">
                             <xsl:choose>
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:RXA.3)= 0">
                                <dil:message type="error">RXA-3 Date/Time Start of Administration not found but is required.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:RXA.3)> 1">
                                <dil:message type="error">Only one Date/Time Start of Administration (RXA-3) allowed per Order Segment.</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when> 
                                 <xsl:when test="count(a:RXA.3)= 1">
                                     <dil:message type="info">Valid value of '<xsl:value-of select="./a:RXA.3"/>' found for Administered Amount (RXA-6).</dil:message>
                                 </xsl:when>
                               </xsl:choose>
                          </xsl:for-each>     
                                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                                            <xsl:analyze-string regex="([&quot;|'])(.*?)\1" select="$TS1Field">
                                <xsl:matching-substring>
                                    <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) '<xsl:value-of select="$TS1Field"/>' found in message, but contains invalid apostrophes or quotes within the value text.</dil:message>
                                </xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    <dil:message type="info">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) '<xsl:value-of select="$TS1Field"/>' found in message.  If any validation errors are found, they will follow this message. </dil:message>
                                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            </xsl:analyze-string>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,1,4) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="^(19|20)\d{{2}}$" select="substring($TS1Field,1,4)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for year not a valid year as required.  Valid years have century of 19 or 20.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,1,4)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,5,2) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="0[1-9]|1[0-2]" select="substring($TS1Field,5,2)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for month not a valid month as required.  Valid months are 01-12.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,5,2)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,7,2) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]" select="substring($TS1Field,7,2)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for day not a valid day value as required.  Valid days are 01-31.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,7,2)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,9,2) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]" select="substring($TS1Field,9,2)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for hour not a valid hour value as required.  Valid values are 00-23.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,9,2)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,11,2) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]" select="substring($TS1Field,11,2)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for hour not a valid for minute not a valid minute value as required.  Valid values are 00-59.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,11,2)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,13,2) !=''">
                                    <xsl:analyze-string regex="0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-9]|5[0-9]" select="substring($TS1Field,13,2)">
                                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                            <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value for seconds not a valid seconds value as required.  Valid values are 00-59.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="substring($TS1Field,13,2)"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                   </xsl:for-each>         
                   <xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="substring($TS1Field,15,1) !=''">
                                    <dil:message type="error">Patient Death Date and Time (PID-29) value is too long.  Valid format is CCYYMMDD.  Found value '<xsl:value-of select="$TS1Field"/>' in message.</dil:message>
                                </xsl:when>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                   </xsl:for-each>  
                       </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose> 
             </xsl:for-each>      
        </dil:filterruleresult>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is cluttered with unrelated code which is slightly confusing. Try to identify and isolate the problem beforehand. For your next question you might want to look at http://sscce.org/ first.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. I have two sets of code:  one is the XML message I'm trying to validate and the other is the validation XSLT.

Comment: Then read the information given in the link. And another thing: On StackOverflow you should _accept_ answers that solved your problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring the

```
<xsl:variable name="TS1Field" select="/a:VXU_V04/a:VXU_V04.ORDER/a:RXA/a:TS.1"/>
```

but there are no `TS.1` elements that are direct children of `RXA` (they're all inside `RXA.3` or `RXA.4`), so the variable is set to the empty sequence, and thus

```
<xsl:analyze-string regex="([&quot;|'])(.*?)\1" select="$TS1Field">
```

will complain with the error you're seeing.  But since you're inside a

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">
```

it might make more sense to analyze `a:TS1` instead of `$TS1Field` (i.e. the `TS1` inside the particular `RXA.3` you're currently looking at).

Comment: Thanks!  I see where I didn't declare that variable correctly.  I fixed it but I'm still getting the same error message (although now it looks like this:  A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the @select attribute of xsl:analyze-string ("20090415132511", "20090531132511", ...).  Also, if I use a:TS.1 instead of $TS1Field, I get this error:   Axis step child::element({urn:hl7-org:v2xml}TS.1, xs:anyType) cannot be used here: the context item is an atomic value

Comment: @InComputero once you fix the path then that variable will contain a sequence of _all_ the `TS.1` elements inside _all_ the orders in the document.  In fact in this case all your `substring` calls that manipulate that variable should _also_ fail with a type error (as the first argument of `substring` is has to be convertible to `xs:string?`).  So `a:TS.1` is definitely the way to go, but for the XSLT you've given in the question the context item will be a node.  Is the question definitely consistent with the stylesheet you're testing?

Comment: Hi Ian, you've asked me something that goes beyond what my non-programmer brain can answer!  I'm not sure how to answer.

Comment: @InComputero what I mean is that if you have `<xsl:analyze-string regex="([&quot;|'])(.*?)\1" select="a:TS.1">` directly inside `<xsl:for-each select="a:RXA/a:RXA.3">` then the "context item is an atomic value" error can't happen.  Are you sure that the structure of your real stylesheet is the same as you've pasted into the question?